# Creating series from variables updated every minute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

So Im making a program where the variables fastMA and slowMA below are calculated every minute (below). I am trying to figure out a way to add each instance they are calculated to a series so that I can compare the most recent minute's values with what they were in the last minute. So I only need the two most recent calculations for each.

```
if len(dfC) >= 75:

    fastMAcloses = pd.DataFrame(dfC.tail(20)).values
    fastMA = fastMAcloses.sum() / 20
    print(fastMA)

    slowMAcloses = pd.DataFrame(dfC.tail(75)).values
    slowMA = slowMAcloses.sum() / 75
    print(slowMA)

else:
    print('... calculating MAs in', 75 - len(dfC), 'min')
```

What ive come up with so far is:

```
    columnsMA = ['Fast MA:', 'Slow MA:']
    valuesMA = [fastMA, slowMA]
    listMA = list(valuesMA)
    seriesMA = pd.Series(listMA, columnsMA)
    print(seriesMA)
```

However with this each time theyre calculated, the new minute's values overwrite the previous ones so they can't be compared. If you can help I thank you so much!

Comment: The `shift()` method may help. For e.g. `df['a'].shift()` will be a new series with the same length, but every row shifted down by one, so say `df['a'] + df['a'].shift()` will be the sum of the current value and the previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something similar to the following:

```
columnsMA = ['Time:','Fast MA:', 'Slow MA:']

#Initiate results
results=pd.DataFrame([[datetime.datetime.now(),fastMA,slowMA]],columns=columnsMA)
                print(results)

#Append to results (say every minute)
dfTemp=pd.DataFrame([[datetime.datetime.now(),fastMA,slowMA]],columns=columnsMA)
results=results.append(dfTemp,ignore_index=True)
print(results)

#Append to results (say every minute)
dfTemp=pd.DataFrame([[datetime.datetime.now(),fastMA,slowMA]],columns=columnsMA)
results=results.append(dfTemp,ignore_index=True)
print(results)

    ... keep appending to the dataframe ....
```

There is also a concat function which you could investigate further.

I guess that if you wanted to only keep 2 separate minutes of data in memory rather than the full history, you could just build a data frame from the tail and the new calculation results.